# torchtext. loading data and labels that stored into lists

Tags: python, torchtext

I have the list of texts and the list of corresponding labels, 0 or 1. My purpose is to use torchtext `torchtext.Field.build_vocab` and next `torchtext.data.BucketIterator.splits` to create an iterator object. But I have no idea and I cannot find any information about work with lists in torchtext. I would be very happy to get any help and hints